# Footer do not automatically position itself beneath the content

Tags: css, reactjs, footer, react-bootstrap

On my website, I am struggling to get the footer always at the bottom of the page but I mean at the bottom of the page below the content. It seems that in my case the footer stays always position at the height of the screen instead of being below the content and adjust its position.

This what it looks like:

[image]

below is the code of the App.js who handle the `layout`-ing

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';


import Home from './pages/Home';
import NoPages from './pages/NoPages';
import Discover from './pages/Discover';
import HowItWorks from './pages/HowItWork';
import CreateClassAndHost from './pages/CreateClassAndHost';
import Profile from './pages/Profile';
import Messages from './pages/Messages';
import Settings from './pages/Settings';
import Logout from './pages/Logout';
import CreateClass from './pages/CreateClass';
import CreateHost from './pages/CreateHost';
import HereIsTheMission from './pages/HereIsTheMission';
import SuccessfullSubmission from './pages/SuccessfullSubmission';
import CreateHostOnBoardingForm from './pages/HostCreationOnBoarding/CreateHostOnBoardingForm';
import CreateClassOnBoardingForm from './pages/ClassCreationOnBoarding/CreateClassOnBoardingForm';

import './App.css';

function App()  {
    return (
      <div className="app-container">
        <div class="app-header">
          <div class="app-header-menu">
            <Header />
          </div>
        </div>
        <Router>
        <div className="page-content">
          <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={ Home } />
          <Route path="/discover" component={ Discover } />
          <Route path="/howitworks" component={ HowItWorks } />
          <Route path="/create" component={ CreateClassAndHost } />
          <Route path="/profile" component={ Profile } />
          <Route path="/messages" component={ Messages } />
          <Route path="/settings" component={ Settings } />
          <Route path="/logout" component={ Logout } />
          <Route path="/hereisthemission" component={ HereIsTheMission } />
          <Route path="/createaclass" component={ CreateClass } />
          <Route path="/createahost" component={ CreateHost } />
          <Route path="/successfull" component={ SuccessfullSubmission } />
          <Route path="/onboardingclasscreation" component= { CreateClassOnBoardingForm} />
          <Route path="/onboardinghostcreation" component= { CreateHostOnBoardingForm } />
          <Route path="*" component={ NoPages } />
          </Switch>
        </div>
        </Router>
        <div class="app-footer">
          <div class="app-footer-menu">
            <Footer/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

export default App;
```

and the associated css:

```
body,html{
    height :100%;
}
  
.app-container{
    display :flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:space-between;
    height:100%;
}

.app-header{
    background-color:white;
    padding:10px;
  }

.app-header-menu{
    background-color:white;
    padding:10px;
    width:100vw;
}

.app-footer{
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    }
    
.app-footer-menu{
    padding:10px;
    background-color:white;
    width:100vw;
}

.page-content {
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Any idea to always make sure the footer is at the bottom below the content. Thanks

Comment: don't repeat the same question

Comment: The question has been closed previously and not solved. @TemaniAfif

Comment: @RedBaron I got a good exercice for you :-) So none of the solution proposed works. the footer is fixed on the bottom of the page but if the content is higher that the page, the footer overlap the content

Answer (score 0):

`position:fiexd;` can solve the issue, but if you can create a working demo, I can suggest better solution also:

```
.app-footer{
    position:fiexd; // <---- HERE
    bottom:0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

---

You can also do something like this :

```
.app-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh; // <--- provide some min height so footer stick to footer
  position: relative; // <--- provide position relative
}

.app-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**WORKING DEMO** : (you can check the footer by changing the content)

[image: Edit magical-poincare-ovm7p]

Comment: So I cannot use fixed because it stuck the footer at the bottom of the screen not at the bottom but always below the content

Comment: @Seb, you can check the second solution in that case, see the demo

Comment: no much chance to make it works

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 classes and add classes in sibling elements

```
.sticky--footer {
 position: fixed;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0 .2rem; // depends on need
 height: var(--footerHeight);
 }

.with--footer {
  padding-bottom:. var(--- footerHeight)
 }
```

Comment: I am not sure to understand how to do it. I have updated the code in my description. IF you could use it as reference, it would be great